# R: Displaying calculations in graph title

Tags: r, charts

I have this code:

```
    z <- rnorm(20, mean = 5, sd = 1)
    hist(z, 
     main =substitute(paste("Title: " (hat(X), "=",x, sep=" ")), list(x=mean(z))), 
     xlab="z", xlim=c(2,8))
```

And I get this graph:

[image]

This is almost what I want, only I don't know how to do get rid of the comas after hat(X), the equal sign and the number in the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those brackets should be strings.  Try this instead:

```
hist(z, xlab="z", xlim=c(2,8),      
    main = substitute(paste("Title: (", hat(X), "=", x, ")")
         , env=list(x=mean(z))
    )
  )
```

Also, note that this `paste` does not take a `sep` argument.